# iOS Documents Directory expand tilde in path method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Just got a -1 for my answer on how to get the documents directory. I always do it like this:

```
NSString *documentsPath = [@"~/Documents" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
```

And it always works as I expect it to. Are there any real underwater rocks with this method?

Comment: I guess 'Documents' can be considered Hardcode. Although I'm confident that it works +99 % of the time

Comment: @Merlevede no, it works `100%` of the time. And it's way more convenient than writing the routine of searching the documents directory. It doesn't really `feel` right, but it does the job perfectly fine

Comment: I believe you. Rigorously speaking, to be reliable it must be documented, there must be a place where it says that the documents directory will always be called 'Documents'

Comment: The title says "iOS" but it's tagged with `cocoa`. Which one do you really mean? `cocoa` is for OS X. Perhaps it should be tagged `cocoa-touch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does NOT always work. If your app is running in sandbox (which is required by the app store), you won't be able to get the real documents directory.

I just did some test and below is what I got:

```
/Users/<user-name>/Library/Containers/<app-name>/Data/Documents
```

But my real document foder is

```
/Users/<user-name>/Documents
```

Answer (score 0):

Right method to call: `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains()`

As Apple documentation states:

> Creates a list of path strings for the specified directories in the
>   specified domains. The list is in the order in which you should search
>   the directories. If expandTilde is YES, tildes are expanded as
>   described in stringByExpandingTildeInPath.

Example:

`NSString *documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)`